# Webmin How to remove redirection page and immediately redirect to HTTPS when logging

Tags: http, redirect, vps, http-redirect, webmin

I’m trying to log into Webmin using example.com, but I’m currently required to use https://example.com or I get a redirection [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMuhK.png). How can I remove this page and immediately redirect to the HTTPS version of the website when logging into Webmin? Is there a setting or configuration option in Webmin that would allow me to achieve this?